# segmentation fault for while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am trying to use the harversine function after scannig the test file

> stoptimes.txt

I have defined the macro `STOPTIMES` as

```
#define STOPTIMES  "/Users/21107195/Desktop/google_transit/stop_times.txt"
```

and each from each line fgets trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_id,stop_sequence,pickup_type,drop_off_type,timepoint as 
324155,06:32:00,06:32:00,23789,1,0,0,1 respectively

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

//CONDITION FOR NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS
if(argc!=6){
    printf("error: number of arguments must=5");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
else{
    //CONVERT LATITUDES AND LONGITUDES TO DOUBLE
    double start_lat=atof(argv[2]);
    double start_long=atof(argv[3]);
    double end_lat=atof(argv[4]);
    double end_long=atof(argv[5]);

    //CHECK TO SEE IF ARGUMENT LATS AND LONGS ARE VALID
         if(!valid_location(start_lat,start_long)||!valid_location(end_lat,end_long)){
        printf("invalid starting location: lat=%lf long=%lf\n",start_lat, start_long);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{


printf("valid locations: start lat=%lf start long=%lf end lat=%lf end long=%lf\n",start_lat,start_long,end_lat,end_long);
        int trip_id;
        int hour;
        int minute;
        int stop_id;
        int distance_start_stop1;
        //DECLARE FILE POINTER
        FILE *stoptimes;

        //OPEN FILE stops.txt
        stoptimes=fopen(STOPTIMES, "r");
        if(stoptimes==NULL){
            printf("cannot open file stoptimes.txt");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //CREATE ARRAY TO STORE LINE OF stops.txt
        char line[BUFSIZ];

        //CONDITIONAL VARIABLE FOR WHILE LOOP
        int count=0;
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stoptimes)!=NULL){
            if(count>0){
                sscanf(line,"%d,%d:%d:%*d,%*d:%*d:%*d,%d,%*d,%*d,%*d,%*d",&trip_id,&hour,&minute,&stop_id);
                printf(".%d\n",count);
                distance_start_stop1=(int)haversine(start_lat,start_long,getlat(stop_id),getlong(stop_id));

                printf("\n");
            }
            count++;
        }


        //CLOCE FILE STOPTIMES.TXT
        fclose(stoptimes);
```

}

Everytime I run the code it runs for between 300 and 100 times depending on how many functions are called after using the sscanf function and returns a segmentation fault 11.

This is the code for

> getlat(stop id)

where the stops file is

```
#define STOPS "/Users/21107195/Desktop/google_transit/stops.txt"
```

and the line should print out the following way
location_type, parent_station, stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_desc, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id 0,,10000,10000,"Albany Hwy After Armadale Rd","",-32.1479054960,116.0201957650,4 where values a repsctively

```
double getlat(int stop_id){
int comstop_id;
double stop_lat;

//DECLARE FILE POINTER
FILE *stops;

//OPEN FILE stops.txt
stops=fopen(STOPS, "r");

//CREATE ARRAY TO STORE LINE OF stops.txt
char line[BUFSIZ];

//CONDITIONAL VARIABLE FOR WHILE LOOP
int count=0;


//WHILE LOOP GETTING LINES OF stop.txt
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stops)!=NULL){

    if(count>0){
        if(isdigit(line[2])){ 
                 sscanf(line,"%*d,%*d,%d,%*d,%*100[^,],%*100[^,],%lf,%*lf,%*s",&comstop_id,&stop_lat);
        }
        else{
                       sscanf(line,"%*d,,%d,%*d,%*100[^,],%*100[^,],%lf,%*lf,%*s",&comstop_id,&stop_lat);
        }
        if(comstop_id==stop_id){
            break;
        }

    }
    count++;
}
printf("latitude:%lf/n",stop_lat);
fclose(stops);
return stop_lat;
}
```

**the fuction for getlong is the same except it retunr the value3 of the longitude

this is the function for haversine**

```
    double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
double deltalat = (lat2 - lat1) / 2.0;
double deltalon = (lon2 - lon1) / 2.0;

double sin1     = sin( degrees_to_radians(deltalat) );

double cos1     = cos( degrees_to_radians(lat1) );
double cos2     = cos( degrees_to_radians(lat2) );

double sin2     = sin( degrees_to_radians(deltalon) );

double x        = sin1*sin1 + cos1*cos2 * sin2*sin2;

double metres   = 2 * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METRES * asin( sqrt(x) );

return metres;
}

double degrees_to_radians(double degrees){
return (degrees * M_PI / 180.0);
}
```

Comment: Run this in a debugger and observe the crash live. And some output-ghetto debugging (clipping code, debug printfs, etc) certainly wouldn't hurt. In the meantime, I'm off to polish up the crystal ball on the hope it will divulge what `BUFSIZ`  et'al are, as a segfault 11 is traditionally a stack overflow (ironic indeed).

Comment: There are two usual causes of segmentation fault: Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, or accessing outside the bounds of an array. Since you don't have any pointers in your code, it's probably the array bounds problem. Running your program with `valgrind` can help diagnose problems like this.

Comment: What is value of  `BUFSIZ` ?

Comment: use gdb or some other debugger

Comment: @WhozCraig, ameyCU : BUFSIZ is defined in stdio.h. It's [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html) According to GNU libc manual its value "is chosen on each system so as to make stream I/O efficient". On my system it goes to _G_BUFSIZ in libio.h, which goes to _G_BUFSIZ form _G_config.h, value 8192.

Comment: @jbm thanks for the info. indeed on my clang 3.6 rig (osx) it is 1024 which should certainly be reasonable for activation space as I see no recursion. Thanks again!.

Comment: That `scanf(3)` call requires up to 20 parameters after the format string.  You have only provided a few... That's the reason of the crash.

Comment: na it doesnt because i have flag those parameters